# Mutating slot 0 of a storage array in Solidity assembly

Tags: solidity, storage, arrays

Have been working on a function allow users to edit specific types of state using Solidity assembly, and ran into some unexpected behavior.

According to [the documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage), for a storage array `arr` located at position `p`, the value at `p` (i.e. `p + 0`) is the length of the array (i.e. does not store data):

> For dynamic arrays, this slot stores the number of elements in the array.

And yet, when I attempt to mutate the value stored at position `0` (`p + 0`) using `sstore`, in fact it is the first element of the array `arr[0]` which is affected. I would have expected to need to add an additional offset (i.e. `p + 1`) to reach location `arr[0]`.

Did I misunderstand the documentation? Does Solidity assembly know enough about the underlying storage structure to prevent me from mutating the array length directly?

---

Here is the function used to determine the location to be mutated. The idea is that you begin with a base storage location of a mapping, and then process a sequence of mapping keys or offsets to get the final storage location for your variable.

```
  bool constant MAPPING = false;
  bool constant OFFSET = true;

  function changeState(
    bytes32 baseSlot,
    bool[] memory mask,
    bytes32[] memory keys,
    bytes32 value
  )
    public
  {
    require(mask.length == keys.length, "bad-num-keys");
    bytes32 slot = baseSlot;

    for (uint256 i; i < keys.length; i++) {
      if (mask[i] == MAPPING) {
        slot = keccak256(abi.encode(keys[i], slot));
      }
      if (mask[i] == OFFSET) {
        slot = bytes32(add(uint256(keys[i]), uint256(slot)));
        if (i != keys.length - 1) { // If not last offset
          slot = keccak256(abi.encode(slot));
        }
      }

    assembly {
      sstore(slot, value)
    }
  }
```

And here is the storage structure I am working with:

```
struct MyStruct {
 address addr;
 uint256 val1;
 uint256 val2;
 uint256[] otherVals;
}

mapping(uint256 => MyStruct) myStructs;
```

Using this code, I was expecting to pass the following to edit the first value of the `otherVals` storage array, located in the `myStructs` mapping with a key of `0`:

```
const baseSlot = myStructs_slot;
const mask = [F, T, T];
const keys = [0, 3, 1];
```

But  found that the following worked:

```
const baseSlot = myStructs_slot;
const mask = [F, T, T];
const keys = [0, 3, 0];
```

Comment: So how exactly do you "attempt to mutate the value stored at position 0"?

Comment: Using `sstore(p, value)`

Comment: I meant, show your entire code. Need to know how `p` is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I think I figured it out!

My error -- if `p` is the "location" of the array, then `keccak(p)` is the location of the data, so `keccak(p) + 0` would give the first data value. I incorrectly interpreted `keccak(p)` as the place where the array length is stored (i.e. `[length, val0, val1, ...]`), while in reality we have something more along the lines of `length` at position `p` and `[val0, val1, ...]` at a completely different `keccak(p)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to set a storage array's length using `sstore`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Tata
{
    uint256[] public testArray;

    function getLength() external view returns (uint256)
    {
        return testArray.length;
    }
    function setLength(uint256 newLength) external
    {
        assembly { sstore(testArray_slot, newLength) }
    }
}
```

You can use the `_slot` suffix to get the storage address of a storage array.

I wonder what you're doing differently. Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

I Think the problem is that P+0 is represented by either:

1) ~p meaning the array does not exist and has not been created. as a result the value cannot be manipulated.

or

2) is p(0) which becomes p(0+0)=0 unfortunately that is only the case when you take machine code and evaluate it using the human language to interpret it.

index 0 is item 1 within the array. it's not treated as nothing.

so p (the array of an unknown number of indexes) is just p, but p(0) is actually p(1) or 
p of x = (p*x)
p*1 = p

when p is at array 0 it is just p (an empty set of 1 that is all that makes up p (which is not an array, but a value.)

p(1) is actually P (in and of itself) plus (p of 1) or p and the item that is separate from it but part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Length of dynamic array is stored separately from its elements, so, if `p` is address of array length, then `keccak256 (p) + i` is the address of i-th element of the array.  So, your core should look like this:

```solidity
if (mask[i] == OFFSET) {
  slot = bytes32(add(uint256(keys[i]), uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(slot)))));
}
```

See [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/miscellaneous.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays) for details.